# Get category ID by category name

Tags: category, array, name

I have an array with 3 categories names:

```
$arr = ['onecat','twocat','threecat'];
```

How can I get the IDs from this categories? For example in other array.

Comment: which maagento version ,you have using

Comment: The version is 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a category Collection in 1.x Version then filter That Collection  in condtion;

```
    $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('name',['in' =>$arr]);
```

Then those category ids by **getAllids()**

```
$collection->getAllIds();
```

**Or:**

```
 $collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('name',['in' =>$arr])->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $category) {
echo $category->getId();

}
```

Comment: Oh perfect! ;) Its work!